# Copying content of 2 files in a new file by pairing the values in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

There are supposed to be 2 files. One file has list of users and the other files has list of passwords. 
User file has 5 users and password file also has 5 passwords. What I have to do here is create a new file and pair each user with all the available passwords in password file. For example: user 1 is to be paired with password 1, 2,3,4,5. user 2 is to be paired with password 1,2,3,4,5 and so on.

My question is: 
1. What loop should be used here? 
2. My head says for pairing we need to use nested for loop. is it correct? 
3. I can somehow imagine the 1st part of copying the contents but I'm not able to picture how to pair them. So I need help and suggestions.

EDIT:

Sample input are the 2 files named Username and Password.

**Username file:**

User1

User2

..

User5

**Password file:**

Pass1

Pass2

..

Pass5

**Expected output is:**

User1-Pass1

User1-Pass2

..

User1-Pass5

User2-Pass1

User2-Pass2

..

User2-Pass5

and so on till we reach User5-Pass5

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad 1., 2. Yes, nested loop required.

Let's expect one user per line and one password per line, then code would be:

```
> concat  # delete file content
for usr in `cat file_with_users`
do  
    for pwd in `cat file_with_passwords`
    do
        echo "$usr-$pwd" >> result_file
    done 
done
```

If you write input sample and expected output, I can write something more specific.

Comment: hi @Enkeli. Sample input would be lets say file 1 has 1 user per line .. so I assume it to be User 1 , User 2, User 3, User 4 and User 5.  File 2 has Pass1, Pass2, Pass3, Pass4 and Pass5. 

Expected output is: 1. A new file. 2. User 1 - Pass1
User 1 - Pass2, User 1 - Pass3, User 1 - Pass4, User 1 - Pass 5.
User 2 - Pass1 and so on

Comment: also, in the above code do we have to pass the directory we are working in?

Comment: This code suppose current working directory, create two files - user and passwords, and you will see the result. Try it!

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I got the output as expected. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I have another question.. for redirecting our output we have to a new file do we have to use ">" or ">>"?

Comment: ">" if file already exists, this deletes its content, otherwise creates new empty file. 


">>" means append - if file doesn't exists, creates one, if file exists then adds text to the end

Comment: I noticed ">>" this creates a new file like you said. 
Also I tried redirecting output to already existing file by using ">" the output I got was User5-Pass5

Comment: it should be User5-Pass5.. ">" deletes file content (or deletes file and creates new - not sure what's correct)... but for you is important, that ">" **always** deletes content and writes new...so only the last statement is echo-ed there

Answer (score 1):

always there is a better way

```
$ join -t, -j 99 users pwords | cut -d, -f2-
```

for example

```
$ echo u{1..5} | tr ' ' '\n' > users
$ echo p{1..5} | tr ' ' '\n' > pwords

$ join -t, -j 99 users pwords | cut -d, -f2-
u1,p1
u1,p2
u1,p3
u1,p4
u1,p5
u2,p1
u2,p2
...
u5,p4
u5,p5
```

for `-` delimiter change to `join -t- -j 99 users pwords | cut -d- -f2-`

This is using a fictional column (99th) to create a join between each rows, which is called cross-product.  Since the key is missing in the first position of the output we need to cut it out at the end.

Comment: hi @karakfa. This is also interesting. Is this approach going to work when inputs are 2 files (1 username and 1 password per line) and expected output is again the pairing you've done but in a new file?

Comment: sure, that's how the example I set up.  The output you have to direct to a file as usual `... | cut .. > outputfile`

Answer (score 0):

Do either of these help:

```
grep -Fwf file1 file2 or 
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$1 in A' file1 file2
```